# Unable to refresh token for multiple resource in azure java sdk

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-java-sdk

When trying to call two different resources after being authorised through the redirect URL, the first call finishes and the second call fails to refresh its token with `"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"`.
In the code below the call to the second service always fails (even when changing the order of the calls or calling the first service multiple times)

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials applicationTokenCredentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
DelegatedTokenCredentials delegatedTokenCredentials = new DelegatedTokenCredentials(applicationTokenCredentials, redirectUrl, code);
Azure.Authenticated azureAuth = Azure.authenticate(delegatedTokenCredentials);

//First call - resource : https://management.core.windows.net/
azureAuth.subscriptions().list();

//Second call - resource : https://graph.windows.net/
azureAuth.servicePrincipals().list();
```

After some debugging i found that the following function on the Azure SDK fails : `(com.microsoft.azure.credentials.RefreshTokenClient)`

```
AuthenticationResult refreshToken(String tenant, String clientId, String resource, String refreshToken, boolean isMultipleResourceRefreshToken) {
    try {
        RefreshTokenResult result = service.refreshToken(tenant, clientId, "refresh_token", resource, refreshToken)
            .toBlocking().single();
        if (result == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new AuthenticationResult(
            result.tokenType,
            result.accessToken,
            result.refreshToken,
            result.expiresIn,
            null,
            null,
            isMultipleResourceRefreshToken);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you granted the azure ad graph api permission to your AD App?

Comment: Yes, also if i call the graph api first than it works fine and the request to management api fails. The second call always fails.

Comment: Have you changed the resource to the correct one when you use the first refresh token to request the new access token and second refresh token?

Comment: Not sure i follow. I run the code mentioned above - is there some step i am missing?

Comment: The code looks fine, but I am not sure if you pass the correct `resource` in the refreshToken()? I mean if you use the refresh token to acquire the new access token with resource `https://management.core.windows.net/`, then the new access token will not be able to call the azure ad graph api `https://graph.windows.net/`.

Comment: The refreshToken() code is part of the Azure SDK.https://github.com/Azure/autorest-clientruntime-for-java/blob/a55f87f3cc3a68742a2ac94c031c6d715965a9c2/azure-client-authentication/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/credentials/RefreshTokenClient.java

Answer (score 1):

The 1.6.13 release for the `azure-client-authentication` fixes the issue by removing the `RefreshTokenClient` and replacing it with the refresh token utility in the adal4j library: https://github.com/Azure/autorest-clientruntime-for-java/releases/tag/v1.6.13. You can try updating to this version.